# SAS: alternatives to First. and Last. variables when data can not be sorted?

Tags: sorting, sas, transpose

Please help me with the following SAS problem. I need to transform my data set from "original" to "new" as shown in the picture. Because the "priority" variable can not be sorted, it seems that first. and last. variables would not work here, no? The goal is to have each sequence of priorities represent one entry in the "new" dataset.

Thank you!

p.s. I did not know how to create a table in this post so I just took a snapshot of the screen.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZvpB.png]

Comment: Why can't you sort? Add a record ID, sort, process, and the resort to original desired order. Please post your data as text in a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems fairly straightforward to me.  Just create a batch ID.

```
data have_pret;
  set have;
  by subject;
  if first.subject then batchID=0;
  if priority=1 then batchID+1;
run;
```

Then you can transpose by subject/batchID.  This assumes priority always starts at 1 - if it starts at > 1 sometimes, you may want to adjust your logic and keep track of prior value of priority.